# Joining two tables of similar structure

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle12c, join

I have 2 same type of tables:T1 and T2 with 4 column (Date,flag,status,counts). I want to take the difference of counts in tables.I'm Using below query

```
`Select 
T1.date,
T1.flag,
T1.status,
T1.counts,
T2.counts
(T1.count-T2counts)as difference 
From T1
Left join T2
On T1.date=T2.date
And T1.flag=T2.flag
And T1.status=T2.status
`
```

but unable to get the required output. Any advise will be appreciated.
Sample data and required output is as below
[image]

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` and `group by` to summarize what is in each table:

```
select Date, flag, status, sum(count1) as count1, sum(count2) as count2,
       ( sum(count1) - sum(count2) ) as diff
from ((select Date, flag, status, counts as count1, 0 as count2 from table1) union all
      (select Date, flag, status, 0, counts as count2 from table1)
     ) tt
group by Date, flag, status;
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of typos in your query. I modified it and added a WITH statement so that I can use sample data. The results look nice.

```
with T1 (mydate, flag, status, counts) as (select trunc(sysdate), 'Cat1', 1, '100' 
from dual), 
    T2 (mydate, flag, status, counts) as (select trunc(sysdate), 'Cat1', 1, '50' 
from dual)
Select 
T1.mydate,
T1.flag,
T1.status,
T1.counts T1Count,
T2.counts T2Count,
(T1.counts-T2.counts)as difference 
From T1
left join T2
On T1.mydate=T2.mydate
And T1.flag=T2.flag
And T1.status=T2.status
```